# SUM(0) function Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum

Hi I'm tuning someone's query that starts with

```
select 
SUM(0) as A_CT,
..
..
```

I don't understand what `SUM(0)` will do here. Can someone please provide meaning behind using `SUM(0)`?

Comment: No idea... perhaps with more context it would become a little clearer. In any case: the sum will be 0, **unless** the query it is part of returns no rows, in which case the sum will be NULL. An idiotic (pardon my French) way to check if a query returns any rows, perhaps?

Comment: It just produces a zero. Maybe that person needed a zero on that column for the rest of the application to work as expected. Who knows...

Comment: Just a guess - perhaps they meant `SUM(1)`? Same as `COUNT(*)`, except that it would produce `NULL` instead of `0` when the row count is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only conceivable use for that would be as a placeholder in one block in a "union all" query selecting from two different sets of data which need to be coerced into the same "shape" for further addition. something like:

```
select sum (a_ct) as a_ct, sum (x_sum) as x_sum from 
(
select sum (0) as a_ct, sum (x_col) as x_sum from x
union all
select sum (y) as a_ct, sum (0) as y_sum from y
)
```

But even then, one would expect it to be expressed as 0 instead of sum (0).

Comment: Or even as NULL, if the intent is to not change SUM(y) (with your notation). That way if all "y" are NULL, the sum will still be NULL in the overall query.

Comment: @mathguy - yes, you're absolutely right. Still can't see why anyone would <start> a query like that though!

Comment: Yes you are right Lord Peter, thank you for understanding this question with a short description.

Comment: FYI - it's a 8 page query with the "UNION ALL" logic so I can't copy here and Lord Peters explanation makes sense.